# UWP: The type or namespace name 'TensorFloat' could not be found

Tags: c#, machine-learning, uwp, ml.net

I am trying to run a UWP app I made (which worked) on a different computer, and I am now getting the error:

> The type or namespace name 'TensorFloat' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have VS 2017, my Windows 10 version is 1809, build 17763.194, and I've installed Windows 10 SDK 10.0.17763.132, but it didn't help. Is there a package I need to install or something like that?

**Edit:**
Changing the target version fixed it, now those errors are gone and the project starts to build. However, it now breaks at

```
 public static async Task<modelModel> CreateFromStreamAsync(IRandomAccessStreamReference stream)
        {
            modelModel learningModel = new modelModel();
            learningModel.model = await LearningModel.LoadFromStreamAsync(stream);
            learningModel.session = new LearningModelSession(learningModel.model); // it breaks here
            learningModel.binding = new LearningModelBinding(learningModel.session);
            return learningModel;
        }
```

and I get a very strange error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Unspecified error
>
> No suitable kernel definition found for op Sub (node Minus675)'

Comment: As the error says... Are you missing a using directive?

Comment: @AFriend I have `using Windows.AI.MachineLearning;`, but it's grayed out.

Comment: Does it have a red squiggly line under it? Because if it's just greyed out, that means you should have the assembly reference. Could you show us the code where this happens?

Comment: No red line, just grayed out. It happens on `TensorFloat inputTensor = TensorFloat.CreateFromArray(new long[] { 1, 1, 64, 64 }, await ConvertImage(file));`. This should happen on some button click, in the main page.

Comment: If you put the cursor on "TensorFloat" and press Ctrl+Period, does it offer any options, like adding a different using directive? Also what happens if you change it to `Windows.AI.MachineLearning.TensorFloat inputTensor = Windows.AI.MachineLearning.TensorFloat.CreateFromArray(new long[] { 1, 1, 64, 64 }, await ConvertImage(file));`?

Comment: @Bas No useful options offered, and `Windows.AI.MachineLearning.TensorFloat` doesn't even exist, it's only offering `Windows.AI.MachineLearning.Preview`.

Comment: Then you are definitely missing the assembly in which TensorFloat is defined. If you look at the project references, are there anything references with the yellow triangle icon?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185198/discussion-between-bas-and-eutherpy).

Comment: The `TensorFloat` class is introduced from 17763, you need to make your project's target version is 17763 at least.

Comment: To make sure that there're no problems with your environment, you could test the official code sample [MNIST](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/tree/850a3394576a36afcfcd1cfde2809a88438ab9d2/Samples/MNIST/UWP) to see if you still face this issue.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT That did it, please see my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ML.NET: strange runtime error on some machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804138/ml-net-strange-runtime-error-on-some-machines)